# Enum values in Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I created a Swagger schema filter like this:

```
public class OpenApiIgnoreEnumSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    private readonly bool _useNames;

    public OpenApiIgnoreEnumSchemaFilter(bool useNames = false)
    {
        _useNames = useNames;
    }

    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Type.IsEnum && !(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(context.Type)?.IsEnum ?? false))
        {
            return;
        }

        Type type = (context.Type.IsEnum ? context.Type : Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(context.Type));
        List<IOpenApiAny> list = new List<IOpenApiAny>();
        string[] names = Enum.GetNames(type);
        int[] values = Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<int>().ToArray();
        foreach (var (text, value) in names.Select((string name, int index) => (name, values[index])).ToList())
        {
            if (!type.GetMember(text)[0].GetCustomAttributes<OpenApiIgnoreEnumAttribute>().Any())
            {
                IOpenApiAny item;
                if (!_useNames)
                {
                    IOpenApiAny openApiAny = new OpenApiInteger(value);
                    item = openApiAny;
                }
                else
                {
                    IOpenApiAny openApiAny = new OpenApiString(text);
                    item = openApiAny;
                }

                list.Add(item);
            }
        }

        schema.Enum = list;
    }
}
```

It works quite well to a point - if I pass it the `true` value in the constructor argument and try to pick a value from a dropdown in the SwaggerUI in the browser it tells me that only integer values are allowed:

[image]

Is there a way to have the functionality provided by the schema filter (stringified enum names + hiding of some members I'd like to hide) and at the same time to be able to use those stringified enums in the UI?

Comment: Try setting `schema.Type = "string";` and `schema.Format = null;`

Comment: Do you use the latest version of swagger?

Comment: @AlirezaSoleimaniAsl yes

Comment: @Alberto your advice worked. Post your answer please, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `schema.Type = "string";` and `schema.Format = null;`

Swagger will show enum names, and will pass the string value into the API. The controller and serializer should be able to handle enum values as strings.